# jQuery Mobile CSS is interfering with my CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, overriding

I am trying to create a web app using HTML, CSS and jQuery Mobile. The issue I am having is that the jQuery Mobile CSS is overriding my CSS wherever I put it inside the head tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title>Mobile App</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device width:480px)"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
```

When I try to center my Logo image using the CSS below, it doesn't have any effect.

```
.logo{
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Any help in solving this overriding CSS issue would be gratefully appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: And it works when you remove jQuery mobile ?

Comment: Make your css selectors [more specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: It works when the jQuery mobile CSS is removed. I have tried to make the selectors more specific but still no change.

Comment: inspect in your browser what styles are applied to the .logo element and which styles are overridden..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different class name in your style, and write what really need to change instead of writing same as jquery mobile css.